# O que é marcar um item como "Landmark" no Eclipse IDE ("Mark as Landmark")?

Tags: eclipse

Estou estudando o *Mylyn* do *Eclipse IDE* e me deparei com a opção *"Mark as Landmark"* que aparece disponível para alguns itens do *Package Explorer*, e fiquei com algumas duvidas sobre o que é isso, para que serve, e como usar:

[image: Opção "Mark as Landmark" no Eclipse IDE]

No gif acima, eu estou com uma Tarefa Ativa, e, o *Package Explorer* está com a opção *"Focus on Active Task"* ligada, a partir disso eu faço as seguintes ações:

1. Clico no Arquivo `Main.java` com o botão direito do mouse e verifico que a opção *"Mark as Landmark"* não está disponível para ele; **porque não está disponível?**
2. Clico no botão `[+]` que está a direita do Arquivo `Main.java` para que seja exibido os "filhos" dele que não fazem parte do *Context*, e então aparece a classe `Main` ([image: Class Main Node]) que está dentro do Arquivo;
3. Então seleciono a classe `Main` que apareceu, e clico com o botão direito do mouse sobre ela, veja que para ela existe a opção *"Mark as Landmark"*;
4. Clico no `[+]` da classe `Main` e são exibidos os "filhos" dela que não fazem parte do *Context*, que são: o atributo `UI` ([image: atributo UI]), o método `main(String[])` ([image: método main]) e o método `start(Stage)` ([image: método start]);
5. Para cada um dos filhos de `Main` que foram abertos na ação anterior, têm-se a opção *"Mark as Landmark"* disponível, mas no gif eu mostro isso apenas para o método `main(String[])`, ao clicar sobre ele com o botão direito do mouse;
6. Clico na opção *"Mark as Landmark"* fazendo com que o método `main(String[])` fique marcado, note que ele ficou em negrito;
7. Clico novamente com o botão direito do mouse sobre o método `main(String[])`, procurando por uma opção que permita desmarcá-lo como *"Landmark"*, mas não encontro! e a opção *"Mark as Landmark"* ainda está disponível para ele mesmo ele já estando marcado (porque? será um bug?). **Como posso Desmarcar o item como Landmark?**

> **Dúvidas Principais:**
>
> - A opção *"Mark as Landmark"* parece estar disponível apenas para Itens que fazem parte do *Context* da Tarefa Ativa, de modo que eu acho que é uma opção relativa ao sistema de *Contexts* das *Tasks* do *Mylyn*; é isso mesmo?
> - O que é e/ou para que serve a opção *"Mark as Landmark"*?
> - Em quais casos é interessante usar a opção *"Mark as Landmark"*?
> - Como usar corretamente a opção *"Mark as Landmark"*?